# SQLite3 Como deletar ultimos registros usando ORDER BY

Tags: android, sql, sqlite3

Eu já pesquisei muito na inter mas não encontrei solução...

Por exemplo, eu tenho um teste de aptidão. Dai eu crio uma tabela: "BDTeste.db", com um banco: "candidatos", com os campos: _id, nome e notas.

Eu lanço primeiro todos os candidatos e só depois do teste, é que eu lanço as suas notas.

Eu ordeno o banco pelas notas da maior a menor (ORDER BY notas DESC). Mas de um teste com 20 candidatos, eu quero deletar as ultimas 15 notas, e aproveitar só as 5 maiores.

Dai eu fiz:

```
try {
     SQLiteDatabase dc = openOrCreateDatabase("DBTeste.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     Cursor res = dc.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM candidatos ORDER BY notas DESC ", null);

     // Criei esta rotina abaixo para apagar os últimos registros, funciona, mas ela é muito grande
     int cont = 0, id = 0;          
     while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
         cont++;
         res.moveToNext();              
         if (cont > 15) {
            id = Integer.valueOf(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            dc.execSQL("DELETE FROM candidatos WHERE _id = '" + String.valueOf(id) + "' ");
         }
     }

     res.close();
     dc.close();           
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tem como fazer este delete usando uma unica linha? Por exemplo, podia ser assim:

```
dc.execSQL("DELETE FROM candidatos WHERE linhas > 15 ");
```

ou seja, apagar os ultimos 15 registros, que são as ultimas 15 linhas do banco...

Agradeço alguma ajuda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se inverter a ordem de ordenação em vez dos últimos serão os primeiros aqueles que quer eliminar.

Se o fizer, pode então usar a cláusula LIMIT para obter apenas os 15 registos que quer eliminar.

```
DELETE FROM candidatos WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM candidatos ORDER BY notas ASC LIMIT 15)
```

Comment: Apenes avalie qual será o critério de desempate caso existam múltiplos candidatos com empate na maior nota a ser eliminada.

Comment: @anonimo É uma boa questão que terá de ser o AP a avaliar/considerar.

Comment: ramaral, tu és um gênio. Deu certo. Sobre o ... critério de desempate... não precisa pois a dúvida acima é um exemplo. O banco real trata com recordes num jogo. Porem eu ainda apanhei um pouco, pois não queria deletar nem a pau. Só deletou depois que eu fechei o cursor ( dc.close e res.close ), daí eu pergunto, não era pra deletar mesmo sem fechar...

Comment: *"...não era pra deletar mesmo sem fechar..."*, depende se o cursor "coloca" um *lock* ou não.

Comment: ramaral, podia explicar melhor?

Comment: Sem mais informação, não.

Comment: Desculpem a todos, eu nao tinha observado antes sobre a necessidade de marcar: "Este comentario adiciona algo util à postagem". Marquei agora.